# The regularity of Markov chains with a threshold

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, formal-languages, regular-language

I am studying Paz's "Introduction to Probabilistic Automata", and there is an exercise I cannot solve:

> Ex. 11, p. 170: Prove that the number of nonregular events of the form $\{x \mid p^A(x) > \lambda\}$, where $A$ is a given $n$-state probabilistic automaton over a single letter is $\leq n$.  ($p^A(x)$ is the probability of acceptance of $x$).

I can rephrase it, for instance, as:

> Let $M$ be a stochastic matrix of dimension $n \times n$ and $a$ be a letter.  There are at most $n$ different values of $\lambda \in [0,1]$ for which  $\{a^k \mid (1, 0, \ldots, 0)M^k(0,\ldots,0,1)^{\mbox{T}} > \lambda\}$ is nonregular.

or, alternatively:

> For a stochastic matrix $M$ of dimension $n \times n$, there are at most $n$ different values of $\lambda \in [0,1]$ such that $\{k  \mid (1, 0, \ldots, 0)M^k(0,\ldots,0,1)^{\mbox{T}} > \lambda\}$ is *not* expressible as $F\cup C$ where $F$ is a finite set and $C = c_0 + c_1\mathbb{N}$.

I am strongly interested in the form those nonregular languages may have, so this could be a good start.  Any help?

([cross-posted to cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16725/the-regularity-of-markov-chains-with-a-threshold))

Comment: What is your definition of non-regular language, doesn't every finite language have to be regular?

Comment: I am using the usual definition of regular, and yes, every finite language is regular: however, there is a typo in the question. :-)  It is now fixed.

Comment: I don't understand the form of your language in the second part.  What are $a$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: @TaraB: I expanded the text of the question, as I'm pretty sure that if a specialist doesn't get it, I probably misworded something :-)  Thanks!

Comment: @MichaëlCadilhac:  Thanks, that's very clear now.  If only I knew anything about stochastic matrices! =]

Comment: @TaraB: Well, I see you are studying algebraic formal language theory, and I believe you can view this question as one about rational power series.  Something like: let $r$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-rational power series described by a $k$-state weighted automaton over a single letter.  Then there are at most $k$ values of $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\{a^n \mid (r, a^n) > t\}$ is nonrational.  What about that ? :-)

Comment: @MichaëlCadilhac:  Actually I don't study algebraic formal language theory, but formal languages in algebra (mainly word problems of groups and semigroups as formal languages).  I haven't gotten around to learning about rational power series yet, because it's never come up in anything I was doing.  I really should, though!

Comment: @TaraB: But those are just a morphism away! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: show $\lim_{k\to\infty}(1,0,\dots,0)M^{pk+i}(0,\dots,0,1)^T$ exists for each integer $1\leq i\leq p$, where $p$ is the period of the accepting state (taking $p=1$ if the accepting state is transient).

Comment: This is **great**! Of course!  This does not say much about the languages that show up (I have a related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167653/for-a-trigonometric-polynomial-p-can-lim-limits-n-to-infty-pn2-0) by the way), but it certainly answers the present question.  Thank you very much.